# How to separate the date and time components of NSDate() in Swift?

Tags: swift, date, time, filtering, nsdate

Would anyone be able to tell me how to separate the date and time components of NSDate() in Swift? I saw a few things about separating the date itself into components (day, month, year), but nothing really about how to get the time only or the day, month, and year only.

Basically, I'm trying to filter data on a table by date, but to also display the time the entry was made. I tried using the plain ol' NSDate(), but then the filtering didn't work because filtering by just today's date didn't yield results because the times those entries were made will always be less than the current time.

Comment: Look into `NSDateComponents`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Calendar to break a date apart, using CalendarUnit to specify what components you want.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .day, .year, .hour, .minute], from: Date())
print("Hour: \(components.hour)")
print("Minute: \(components.minute)")
print("Day: \(components.day)")
print("Month: \(components.month)")
print("Year: \(components.year)")
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 5 Xcode 14.2

```
let myDate = .... // you date here

let cal = Calendar.current
let required : Set<Calendar.Component> = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
let components : DateComponents = cal.dateComponents(required, from: myDate)


print("Hour: \(components.hour)")
print("Minute: \(components.minute)")
print("Day: \(components.day)")
print("Month: \(components.month)")
print("Year: \(components.year)")
```

Comment: Please, edit the accepted question instead of adding your own with a minor fix

Comment: is not minor. 1) original code does not show clear Date() var.  2) I added required components a user cn specify. All for better readability for novice.  YES.. I can omit prints.

Comment: Yes, you have slightly improved the formatting of the existing accepted answer. It should have been an edit.